# Anticollision system and personel real time tracking system interfering

Tags: rf

We are having some problems with either radio frequency interference or EMC/I interference.

There are 2 different units. The one is an anti-collision detection system. The other unit is a real time tracking system.
The one system consist of a type 2 master controller, machine unit, 2x UHF antennas, and 2x VLF antennas. Using 3.2 – 6.8Ghz and 12Ghz, tag using 433Mhz

Our equipment uses the following modules: access points (APs) and tags

1. BLE (2.4GHz)
2. UWB(3.5-10GHz)
3. sub GHz (868 - 920 MHz)

How is it possible that the two systems clash? Our system drops the first system comms by decreasing the comms distance from 7m to 1.5m.

On the first unit a huge magnetic field is energized on the vehicle.

Is it possible that the power modulator or coil on our tag is activated and thus disabling the tag on their unit?

Comment: Sounds like you have a complex system. Unfortunately you’ve not provided enough information for us to understand your system. As with any complex system, pare it back to the minimum that exhibits the problem. Also note when talking to engineers, be sure to ‘qualify and quantify’. I.e. what it is you are referring to and a number. “Huge magnetic field” tells us little. Huge as in a superconducting magnet measured in Tesla?

Comment: Air bag sensors used to be sensitive to radiated bursts of impulse noise in a parking lot !  RF caps fixed that. YOu seem to have some undefined EMI problem. Keep investigating for SNR issues and crosstalk.

Comment: With RF you need to know PCB layouts parts and how things are interconnected because of conducted emissions, without knowing these it would be hard to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Keep investigating with an RF expert to track crosstalk, front-end saturation and SNR issues and update your question.

There are also lists of known car issues.
E.g. look upwards from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_avoidance_system#List_of_cars_with_available_collision_avoidance_features